# Change font in android

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I know this question has been asked many times but still i am not getting it right.So please do help me.I want to change the font of my textviews.I find some code on google and end up doing this

Code

```
public class SliderFont extends TextView {
    public SliderFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/redhead.ttf");
        setTypeface(typeface);
    }
}
```

And used this in my XMl

```
<pocketdocs.indiehustlers.com.pocketdocsv2.Utils.SliderFont
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="AWAITED APPROVAL"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size" />
```

But still I am not getting the desired font.

I have created assets folder like this [image]

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Nah but font is also not changing

Comment: What is problem here.

Comment: Also try putting those two lines in setTypeface method overriding it in TextView class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was'nt any problem in the code,it was just that i was checking change in the xml editor rather than the device so it was not showing up.

P.S-The font change wont take place in xml editor, you will have to run it in emulator or actual device

Answer (score 2):

instead :

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/redhead.ttf");
        setTypeface(typeface);
```

try use :

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/redhead.ttf");
            yourTv.setTypeface(typeface);
```